# Is hiding underlying classes really ideal?

Tags: java

So I've been coding for a long time at this point. I've always written wrapper classes with a lot of private underlying fields that are accessed via helper methods. This is the conventional wisdom, or at least what I've been taught.

Sometimes a user shouldn't be able to easily interact with your code at runtime but...my "hypothesis" is: Utility applications for your desktop, that only you use, should expose underlying classes for easy extensibility. Same with single player games and the like.

It makes sense when you're talking about dealing with generics. If you have a contract for implementation via an interface/abstract it makes sense. Further, this obviously doesn't apply to programs that need to be secure.

To me exposing underlying classes potentially means significantly less code, code that is easier to "reach out and touch (via reflection, classloaders, etc,)" and significant boosts in implementation uniformity across the board.

Wrapper classes can be anything despite the classes they hide, but the classes themselves are the same. Two pieces of code that have the same underlying architecture and classes, that do the same thing, shouldn't have wildly different code should they?

That's the whole point of standards isn't it? My whole question is simply...why? Why is it inherently "good practice" to hide underlying classes, and wrapping them with a collection of methods to do simple things.

I've run into a lot of libs lately that have "Manager" classes (util classes with instanced fields from the constructor...probably not a formal term.) A lot of them make it somewhat difficult to simply check values for debugging. An example is a HashMap that is only accessed using the lib's methods that mess with the value on the way out/in.

So to say invoke .get on the hashmap, or iterate through the entryset for debugging I have to use reflection. Which is a pain, fills my code with tons of try/catches, and takes far more time.

I've actually had to create an agent and visitors to get certain values before they are written into the dataset at the end of a util method! So, yeah..what gives?

Comment: Writing code for debugging purposes is odd, can't you use a debugger to inspect stuff?

Comment: I didn't understand anything

Comment: @RC I haven't seen many debuggers that allow me to pull say..the actual value from a key-value-pair or other dataset in an instanced field..like a HashMap, List<Pair<?,?>>, etc. Usually they just seem to give info like object size. I'm fairly certain YourKit doesn't at least.